# Activating Device Owner using NFC on the same device

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, provisioning-profile, device-owner

I'm trying to activate device owner for an app using the sample apps @Randy has provided in [GitHub](https://github.com/rg1220/AndroidProvisioningTest) (thank, Randy!). I can get the DeviceOwnerCheck sample app to become the device owner using the adb shell dam commands described by Florent [here](http://florent-dupont.blogspot.fr/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html). However, since this is only good for development and cannot be used in production, I needed to use NFC. I was trying to use the other sample app (NFCProvisioner) to do NFC provisioning but it looks like I need 2 devices to accomplish this? Is there a way I can use NFC (or something else) to be able to provision an app as device owner on the same device?

Comment: When trying to provision using NFC from Samsung S5 (Android 4.4.4) to Nexus 7 (Android 5.0.1), getting a "Oops, This device is already set up" error.

Comment: I've gotten past this error but am still trying to figure out enabling device ownership on a single device.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 5.0 there are [several methods](https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices#Key_provisioning_differences_across_android_releases) of provisioning the Device Owner application.

```
+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+-----+----------+
| Deployment scenario | Mode of operation | Provisioning method | 6.0 | 5.0, 5.1 |
+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+-----+----------+
| Corp-liable         | Device owner      | Google Account      | YES |          |
|                     |                   | NFC                 | YES | YES      |
|                     |                   | Activation code     |     | YES      |
+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+-----+----------+
```

If you're using Android pre 6.0, you could use the [Activation code method](https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices#activation_code_method), but this is no longer supported in the the [Android Version](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html)

Newly in [Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html) you can provision the device using Google Account authentication via server using the [Google Play EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/). But this is more corporate focused approach, since you would have to first [register for the EMM Community](https://developers.google.com/android/work/register) in order to gain access to the API and use the required services.